# Главное меню pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Я пользуюсь системой ubuntu. У меня проблема в том, что строка главного меню для pycharm находится теперь наверху рабочего стола, а не наверху непосредственно окна pycharm. Кто знает как его подвинуть?

Comment: Смените графическую оболочку например на XFCE

Comment: Смените ubuntu на windows.